# SecurityException occurred while installig timerJob

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, feature-scope

While i'm tring to install a TimerJob  with the event reciever, i get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Access denied.

I even cheked the trust level on my webconfig and its 'Full'.
The featue also runed with a fram account .
the scope is web.

here is the code :

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

                SPSite site = web.Site as SPSite;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
                    {
                        // make sure the job isn't already registered   
                        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in elevatedSite.WebApplication.JobDefinitions)
                        {
                            if (job.Name == "aaa")
                            {
                                job.Delete();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        // install the job   
                        SITEP_DataBaseSynchronisation.TimerJob.SITEP_DataBaseSynchronisation_TimerJob corpProfileJob = new SITEP_DataBaseSynchronisation.TimerJob.SITEP_DataBaseSynchronisation_TimerJob("aaa", site.WebApplication);

                        corpProfileJob.Properties.Add("WebName", web.ServerRelativeUrl);
                        corpProfileJob.Properties.Add("WebURL", web.Url);
                        corpProfileJob.Properties.Add("Web", web.ID.ToString());
                        corpProfileJob.Properties.Add("Site", web.Site.ID.ToString());

                        // Updates the timer schedule values   
                        //SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
                        //schedule.BeginHour = 18;
                        //schedule.EndHour = 19;
                        //schedule.BeginMinute = 58;
                        //schedule.EndMinute = 00;
                        //schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
                        //schedule.EndSecond = 0;
                        SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
                        schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
                        schedule.EndSecond = 59;
                        schedule.Interval = 15;                  
                        corpProfileJob.Schedule = schedule;
                        corpProfileJob.Update();
                        elevatedSite.WebApplication.JobDefinitions.Add(corpProfileJob);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your timer job cs file override `HasAdditionalUpdateAccess`

```
protected override bool HasAdditionalUpdateAccess()
{
    return true;
}
```

Also try activating feature via SharePoint Management Shell.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the Application Pool Account, doesn't have permission to add/delete jobs to/from the WebApplication. So if you're always activating the feature using the Farm account try remove the RunWithElevatedPrivileges